# twitter-bootstrap-rails loading the wrong version of bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-rails

I am having a really weird problem here.

I installed the twitter-bootstrap-rails gem as followed:

```
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', git: 'git://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails.git', branch: 'bootstrap3'
```

Than, after I ran the generator to setup the files, I ran my server and ended up having this on my application.css file:

```
/*!
 * Bootstrap v2.3.2
 *
 * Copyright 2012 Twitter, Inc
 * Licensed under the Apache License v2.0
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Designed and built with all the love in the world @twitter by @mdo and @fat.
 */
```

I have no idea why it is running version 2.3 of bootstrap. I already went through the gem code and everything is referencing Bootstrap 3.0.3
There is no 2.3 file anywhere.

Comment: Did you tried using just gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', git: 'git://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails.git' I am wondering if the Branch has to do something with it

Comment: If I don't specify the branch, it will use the master branch, which is bootstrap 2.3 only, and I really want to use bootstrap 3

Comment: Thanks. You may find this gem useful. https://github.com/jasontorres/bootstrap-on-rails Hope this solves your problem